# Rails: Passing params from URL to view without looking up the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a URL like `example.com/test/THIS_TEXT`. Now, when a user comes to my URL, I just want to use the "THIS_TEXT" part inside its routed html.erb view as-is.

I know it wouldn't be MVC anymore, but I am trying to avoid some overhead by making the process independent from the model and database. Is there a simple way to directly pass URL params to view in Rails?

UPDATE:

**some code:**

routes.rb

```
get "/d/:token", to: "games#show"
```

---

games_controller.rb

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_game, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def show
        @text = params["token"]
    end
    #other scaffold stuff...
end
```

---

show.html.erb

```
Your entered text is <%= @text %>
```

---

error

ActionController::ParameterMissing in GamesController#show

param is missing or the value is empty

Comment: change your param key: ``@text = params[:token]``

Comment: can you just add this in your show method in the controller: ``raise params[:token].inspect`` - what is the output?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the problem. I had altered the application layout to show notices in every page. That was generating the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you declaring `THIS_TEXT` in your `routes.rb` file?

if if is declared as something like

`get '/test/:this_text'` (note the `:`)

then you can access it as `params[:this_text]` in your controller.

so:

```
# in routes.rb 

get '/test/:test_text', to: 'tests#show_text'

# in tests_controller.rb

class TestsController < ApplicationController

  def show_text
    @text = params[:test_text]
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added some code. As you see the error comes from the right controller#action so I don't think this is a routing problem. Have you ever tried something like this before?

Comment: Nevermind, application.html.erb was the cause of this problem. Your code is solid.

Answer (score 4):

You can access to the params hash doing something like this:

```
<%= params[:name_of_param] %>
```

The name of the param is the same you put in the routes.rb

Comment: I tried this before asking the question, it reports an error as the id is not declared.

Comment: ActionController::ParameterMissing 
param is missing or the value is empty

Comment: Can you show me how the route is declared and how you reference the parameter?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the code for your review.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
@users_param = params[:users_param]
```

In your view:

Any unsafe characters should be automatically escaped, but it could potentially be rather long. This doesn't touch the model or database. It's also not especially anti-MVC, it just happens to not use the model. Breaking MVC would be doing something like executing a database query from your .html.erb file.

Comment: I tried this before asking the question, it reports an error as the id is not declared.

Comment: ActionController::ParameterMissing 
param is missing or the value is empty

Comment: sounds like a routing issue: see RustComet's answer